# Python - Refactor code to remove list from global variable

Tags: python, refactoring

I'm currently working on a ledger implementation, from an index file I open several files that contain transactions, these transactions have a format, I am extracting the data of a transaction and saving it in an object called transaction and all these objects in a list called transactions that is declared as variable global.
I'm looking to refactor the code so that the transaction list isn't a global variable.
Any advice?

```
import fire
from termcolor import colored

DATA_PATTERN = re.compile(r"\d{4}/\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}")
DOLLAR_SIGN = '$'
INDEX = 'index.ledger'

transactions = []


class Transaction:
    def __init__(self, date=None, payee=None, account=None, value=None):
        self.date = date
        self.payee = payee
        self.account = account
        self.value = value


def getTransactionFile():
    with open(INDEX) as indexFile:
        for lineIndex in indexFile.readlines():
            if lineIndex.startswith("!include"):
                pathFile = lineIndex.split()[1]
                with open(pathFile) as transactionFile:
                    for lineFile in transactionFile.readlines():
                        try:
                            if DATA_PATTERN.match(lineFile):
                                date = (lineFile.split()[0])
                                payee = (lineFile.strip(date))
                            if DOLLAR_SIGN in lineFile:
                                account = (lineFile.split()[0])
                                if (lineFile.split()[1]).startswith(DOLLAR_SIGN):
                                    value = (lineFile.split()[1]).strip(DOLLAR_SIGN)
                                elif (lineFile.split()[1]).startswith('-'):
                                    value = (lineFile.split()[1]).replace('$', '')
                                transactions.append(Transaction(date, payee, account, value))
                        except ImportError:
                            print 'Format incorrect in ' + pathFile + ' file'
                            continue


def register():
    getTransactionFile()
    sum = 0.0
    print colored('-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------', 'red')
    print colored(' DATE              PAYEE                      ACCOUNT              VALUE         TOTAL', 'blue')
    print colored('-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------', 'red')
    for x in range(0, len(transactions)):
        total = float(transactions[x].value)
        sum += total
        print '{:^10}     {:25.17}{:^20}{:^20}{:^10}'.format(transactions[x].date, transactions[x].payee,
                                                             transactions[x].account, transactions[x].value, sum)
```

Comment: Use function arguments and `return` values.

Answer (score 1):

compose the `transactions` list into `getTransactionFile()` method and `return` it.

```
def getTransactionFile(transactions):
   transactions = []
   ...
   ...
   return transactions
```

By the way, it depends on how `transactions` list will be used later. I think it does not matter how it is composed.

Answer (score 0):

You culd make transactions its own class.

`class Transactions:
    def __init__():
        self.transactions = []`

Answer (score 0):

Change `getTransactionFile` to take the transaction list as an argument:

```
def getTransactionFile(transactions):
   ...
```

Then declare the transaction list in the caller:

```
def register():
    transactions = []
    getTransactionFile(transactions)
```

You could do the same with the other global variables.